# Lombok @Getter and @Setter unable to get or set values to object

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

Below is my object class:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class MyObject {

    public Long empID;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;


    public MyObject(Long empID, String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.empID = empID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyObject [empID=" + empID + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }

}
```

I tried to use and create an object in another class as below:

```
MyObject myobj = new MyObject();
```

After typing `myObj`, I don't see `getEmpId()` or `getfirstName()` as if I had written explicit getters and setters.

Kindly suggest a solution if I am missing anything here.

Comment: install lombok plugin for your ide.

Comment: You are having parameterized constructor, but while creating new MyObject you are not paasing the values.

Comment: Monzurul Haque Shimul It worked.! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by downloading Lombok plugin from this [Link](https://projectlombok.org/download) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse or one of its offshoots(I am using STS `4.5.1.RELEASE`), all that you need to do is:

- In build.gradle, you **ONLY** need these 2 "extra" instructions:

  ```
  dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'  
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  }
  ```
- Right-click on your project > Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project. The `lombok-"version".jar` will appear inside your project's **Project and External Dependencies**
- Right-click on that `lombok-"version".jar` > Run As > Java Application (similar to double-clicking on the actual jar or running `java -jar lombok-"version".jar` on the command line.)
- A GUI will appear, follow the instructions and one of the thing it does is to copy `lombok.jar` to your IDE's root.

**Note: Remember to restart your IDE and clean all your previously compiled files.**